# jq select a subset of paths selected

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am getting mutiple array of paths contains keywords 'headline' below:

```
jq -c 'paths | select(.[-1] == "headline")' nytimeseuro.json
["data","legacyCollection","collectionsPage","stream","edges",0,"node","headline"]
["data","legacyCollection","collectionsPage","stream","edges",1,"node","headline"]
["data","legacyCollection","collectionsPage","stream","edges",2,"node","headline"]
["data","legacyCollection","collectionsPage","stream","edges",3,"node","headline"]
["data","legacyCollection","collectionsPage","stream","edges",4,"node","headline"]
["data","legacyCollection","headline"]
```

Can I select them based on array index ?
like Output[0:2] select just

```
["data","legacyCollection","collectionsPage","stream","edges",0,"node","headline"]
["data","legacyCollection","collectionsPage","stream","edges",1,"node","headline"]
["data","legacyCollection","collectionsPage","stream","edges",2,"node","headline"]
```

Or Output[-1] select just

```
["data","legacyCollection","headline"]
```

I tried command below , but that seems not to be what I want, it just sliced **each path** I got, rather than select **subset of all paths** returned:

```
jq -c 'paths | select(.[-1] == "headline")[:3]' nytimeseuro.json
["data","legacyCollection","collectionsPage"]
["data","legacyCollection","collectionsPage"]
["data","legacyCollection","collectionsPage"]
["data","legacyCollection","collectionsPage"]
["data","legacyCollection","collectionsPage"]
["data","legacyCollection","headline"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paths` produces a stream, whereas you evidently want an array from which you can easily extract the items of interest.  For example:

```
[paths | select(.[-1] == "headline")][0:2]
```

Stream-oriented alternatives are also available, e.g. limit(2; paths ....)

Comment: A follow up question here I tried 3 commands below : 1) jq -c 'paths | select(.[-1] == "headline")|type' nytimeseuro.json
"array"
"array"
"array"
"array"
"array"
"array"
2) jq '[paths | select(.[-1] == "headline")]|type' nytimeseuro.json
"array"  3) jq '[paths | select(.[-1] == "headline")][0]|type' nytimeseuro.json
"array"  . All of they show the type is 'array' , could you share some links or explain some what is the difference between array/stream in jq and how to tell ? @peak